# How to pass data to python scripts from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, ajax

Here is the HTML file where in scripts portion I made an ajax request to pass some string to python function.

```js
var status = "hello there!!!" 
$.ajax({
      url: "../SCRIPTS/cond.py",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        'status': status
      },
      success: function (data) {
      location.reload(true)
    }
  });
```

Here in `url` I set the path of python scripts. Python file where I want to fetch the requested data from JS and print it.

```py
def main():
    #
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

def test(request):
    print(request)
```

Note: Here I am not using any framework. Just pure HTML, JS and Python file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your backend logic(python script in this case) must be hosted on a http server. An "ajax" request is an http request. You can not POST something to a file on the local file system. Are you running your script on a server? If so, you should be able to access it via a http(s):// type URL.

Comment: Using a relative url is also perfectly valid

Comment: I got it..... I am not using any http server in this case. My main purpose is to write a file from js.. how can i do?